# How to identify flash advertisement in NPAPI plugin

Tags: flash, flash-cs4, npapi

I am writing one NPAPI plugin, which has same MIME type as Adobe flash, so that my plugin will get loaded first.

Actually I just wanted to block the flash based advertisement.
Please suggest any way to identify whether this flash is ad or actual video.
I have looked into NPP_NEW parameters list, but info from this function is not sufficient to detect ads.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: An NPAPI plugin is not really a great choice for the layer to do this at; a browser extension (which is what most ad blockers are) would be much more suited to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can't in general identify ads - they could be working basically the same as non-advertisement Flash usages.

If you want to concentrate on supporting video, you may be able to try the opposite approach:
whitelist known good sites or develop simple heuristics that detect the usage of popular video streaming sites and block everything else.

Alternatively you can block known ads like [ad blockers](http://adblockplus.org/en/) do.

*Note:* When both Adobe Flash and your plugin are installed and support the same mime-types, it is undefined (i.e. browser- and version-dependent) which plugin will be chosen for the content.

Comment: In addition, I've heard from people who would know that some of the browser manufacturers may decide to blacklist your plugin if you're trying to hijack someone else's mimetype.  They were talking specifically about flash...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually making my plugin of same MIME type was just to test my application to block ads.